# Why imported module influence lazy-loaded module in Angular 12?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am reorganizing module structure in nebular-based project. I met situation where imported modules behaves very strangly, i ask you to clarify if you understand how Angular module system works in my situation.

**============================================================**

***Simplified version***

AppModule imports module C(CoreModule) that has UserData provider
AppModule lazy-loads module P(PagesModule) that required UserData
UserData provider not found cuz of lazy-loading
But adding to AppModule import of module S(StrangeModule) that imports module C solves issue, why ? Almost equal imports of C module by AppModule and S module even though working different ways

**============================================================**

***Detailed version***

1. **AppModule** imports **CoreModule.forRoot()** with all services providers - many provide-notations, including **UserData** token.
2. AppModule lazy-loads **PagesModule** for dashboard, layout, cards, etc... components. ***PagesModule have a dependency in UserData service***
3. And there is also some module, call it **StrangeModule**, that was also importing CoreModule.forRoot(), but for now i am trying to exclude this module from project.

**Problem**

There is absolutly no dependency on that StrangeModule(that, i repeat, imports CoreModule.forRoot() second time after AppModule). If i search code for StrangeModule - its only imported in AppModule, no where else.

So, the strange behaviour comes in play when i remove **StrangeModule** from AppModule - then lazy-loaded PagesModule cannot find provider for UserData Service which i guess is okay since PagesModule is lazy-loaded.

**But why the heck if i import StrangeModule in AppModule that dependency is resolved for lazy-loaded PagesModule ?**

AppModule.ts

```js
// output shortened
imports: [...,
CoreModule.forRoot(),
ThemeModule.forRoot(),
NbLayoutModule,
StrangeModule, // why importing this resolves UserData 
//dependency for lazy-loaded module while importing CoreModule itself dont
...]
```

StrangeModule.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    StrangeModuleRoutingModule,
    CoreModule.forRoot(), // remove it and PagesModule also cant resolve UserData
  ],
})
export class StrangeModule {
}
```

PagesModule.ts

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    PagesRoutingModule,
    ThemeModule,
    NbMenuModule,
    DashboardModule,
    ECommerceModule,
    MiscellaneousModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    PagesComponent,
  ],
})
export class PagesModule {
}
```

PagesModule is lazy-loaded only in app-routing.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Probably an issue with nebular module structure. Because in lazy-loaded module i cannot access services provided in CoreModule.forRoot() method. I tried to repeat this structure on a clean Angular project and everything is working as expected